# Number of permutations of a set with an element limited to some positions

Tags: python, permutation

Say I have a combination of digits `[1, 3, 5, 0, 9]`. How can I calculate the number of permutations of the combination where `0` is not at the first position? Also, there may be more than one `0` in the combination.

Comment: You cannot have a set with more than one 0.

Comment: By definition, an element exists only once in a set.

Comment: @planetp no problem, well ch3ka's answer will work even for a list :)

Comment: There are `n!` permutations, `(n-1)!` of which start with a certain element. So the result is `n! - x(n-1)!` where x is the number of zeroes.

Comment: @georg: cool. can you add this as an answer?

Comment: @planetp: this is not entirely accurate, because it doesn't take repeating permutations into account. The real formula would be more complicated. I don't have time now, maybe you could ask on Math.SO?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The literal translation of your problem into python code would be:

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> len([x for x in permutations((1, 3, 5, 0, 9)) if x[0]!=0])
96
```

But note that this actually calculates all the permutations, which would take a long time when the sequence gets long enough.

If all you are interested is the number of possible permutations fitting your restrictions, you'd be better off calculating that number via combinatorial considerations as fredtantini mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that you are talking about list (sets are [not ordered](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) and cannot have an item more than once).

Calculate the number of permutation is a mathematical problem that can be dealed without python: the number of permutation of a set of length 5 is `5!`. As you don't want all the permutations that start with 0, the total number is `5!-4!=96`.

Python has the module [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) with the permutation function. You can use list comprehension to filter the results and calculate the length:

```
>>>[l for l in permutations(list({1, 3, 5, 0, 9})) if l[0]!=0]
[(9, 0, 3, 5, 1), (9, 0, 3, 1, 5), ..., (1, 5, 3, 9, 0)]
>>>len([l for l in permutations(list({1, 3, 5, 0, 9})) if l[0]!=0])
96
```

Comment: `permutations()` works on any iterable - you don't need the cast to `list`. also, naming a variable `l` is discouraged. also, I already answered that ;)

Answer (score 1):

In case I am able to understand your problem, then following logic should work:

```
a = [1, 3, 5, 0, 9]

import itertools
perm = list(itertools.permutations(a))
perm_new = []


for i in range(len(perm)):

    if perm[i][0] != 0:
        perm_new.append(perm[i])
```